# Is it necessary that we have an Primary and Foreign keys on Cross Join

Tags: mysql

I am beginner in SQL I would like to ask that can we performed cross join without keys . I tried on Oracle 10g but I can't able to understand it.

Comment: You can join without keys but a foreign key ensure that you will get a match when you join onto the reference table using foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming by cross join, you mean simple joins (left, right, inner, outer). Cross join occurs when join predicate in tables has many to many relationship. Usually it's not a desirable result. You can read more on this.

https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php

And yes, you can join 2 or more tables without using primary and foreign keys. There are couple of things to note here.
Primary and foreign keys work as indexes on tables to be joined, hence the join is more efficient with keys.
Having primary keys on tables and use it in join criteria ensures that there are no cross join.